# Fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file... But I don't want to open the file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have obtained source code from another developer that I am attempting to build in VS2013. The solution consists of 11 projects: 1 application and 10 static libraries. Included in the file package was a VS project file for 'LibraryX', an 11th static library which is not included in the solution. However, attempting to build the solution gives the error 'cannot open input file libraryx.lib'

After contacting the developer he informed me that this LibraryX is not ready for release and is therefore not included in the source code (the folder containing the necessary cpp and header files is missing). I should therefore be able to build the solution without it. His suggestions were:

> 1. After you open the VS solution, remove the LibraryX library from the solution.

Check (It already wasn't included)

> 2. You also need to remove the libraryx.lib from the linker->input list (on the Properties page of the application project).

Check (Again, it was correctly not in the linker input)

> 3. You may also need to remove the line
>      LibraryX::InitModule();
>      from LibraryABC\libraryabc.cpp as well as remove the include line for LibraryX.h from this file.

I have opened this file and can see the headers and the code block of InitModule() for the other libraries, but LibraryX is not listed. I have searched the entire source code for references to LibraryX and there are none.

How do I find where/why VS is trying to open this file?

Comment: Are you sure you've removed libraryx from all linker LIBRARY directives?

Comment: I would contact that developer and get them to support - they could at the very least send you a version that is working

Comment: Have you checked the linker->input section in your VS project settings? It normally has a list of .lib files to link at link stage.